# Android MP Chart library get X-axis height

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Let's say I have an Activity containing a ChartView (blue rectangle)

[image]

Now, I want to place another View on top of it that will stretch from the X-axis all the way to the top of ChartView.
I tried to do that by setting the margin-bottom equal to the height of the X-axis (red area), but I don't know how to get its height

[image]

How can I achieve this effect? Is there a way to get X-axis height in Android MP Chart? Or maybe there is a walkaround that will have a similar result?
Desirable outcome (the gray area is a view placed on top of the chart):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chart.getXAxis().mLabelHeight returns the height of x-Axis by pixel.
You can get it after OnGlobalLayoutListener, because it is calculated after x-Axis is drawn.

----------Updated Jun 22nd

another way is to use "getHeight() - mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()", but mViewPortHandler is protected, so an extended chart is necessary to provide access to mViewPortHandler

Comment: This does not work. In my case, mLabelHeight returns a value of 18 pixels which is too small, it's half of a whole x-axis. I also tried xAxis.textSize which in my case is 20 pixels, but it's also too small

Comment: It should work, but there is always something unexpected. I tested another  way is to use "getHeight() - mViewPortHandler.contentBottom()", but mViewPortHandler is protected, so an extended chart is necessary to provide access to mViewPortHandler @KamilRadz，please try and see whether it works